# What color should an icon have when used in Action Bar?

Tags: android, colors

I want to make an icon to be used in ActionBar. What color should I use to fill it?

In Android documentation says:

Light theme.

```
Colors: #333333  
Enabled: 60% opacity  
Disabled: 30% opacity
```

Dark theme.

```
Colors: #FFFFFF  
Enabled: 80% opacity  
Disabled: 30% opacity
```

I know how to set opacity in an Android color, but in this case it's a png file.

What hex value should I use, say in Illustrator, to fill an icon to achieve the equivalent of `#FFFFFF 80% opacity`?

And for the other cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For people making their own icons:

Full opacity is 255 (#FF in hex) so for 80% opacity set the alpha to 204 (#CC in hex) and for 60% opacity set it to 153 (#99 in hex).

Answer (score 1):

PNG files support alpha channel (opacity).

If you're really struggling, you can use the [Action Bar and Tab Icon Generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html) (it's maintained by the official Android Design Team) to automatically generate assets for every screen density and with proper opacity values.

Comment: I know that site, but I want an icon made by myself. On the site I have the ability to choose a image but the opacity slider is disabled and only one icon is generated. I need two icons, one for enable and other for disable

Comment: Then make them in illustrator, apply opacity to the layer and save them as PNGs.

Comment: In the site I need to choose custom theme and then the slider is enabled. Thanks.